# How to set width and height for the textview using imagegetter in android

Tags: android, textview

My app consist of a textview and a string, that string contain a **img tag** html code, i'm assign that string to the textview using **ImageGetter** to display the image, and image is retrieving and displaying in the app. But that string also contain **style tag**, which contains both height and width attributes, **now i need to get those attributes values and assign to the mDrawable in onPostExecute().**

Here is my **MainActivity** look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ImageGetter {
private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private TextView mTv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String imgs = "<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/832/832/screwdriver-set/6/3/f/41pcs-aecone-original-imaedhrtthffafup.jpeg?q=70\" style=\"height:100px; width:100px\" />";
    Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(imgs, this, null);
    mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTv.setText(spanned);

}
@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());
    new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

    return d;
}

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String source = (String) params[0];
        mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + params[0]);
        try {
            InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);
            // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
            // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
            CharSequence t = mTv.getText();
            mTv.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

}